# Which name does KFontView show for font subfamily?

Tags: kde, fonts

The font family [`Segoe UI`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220121183930/https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/segoe-ui) (a .ttf font family which has been included with `MS Windows` since at least `Windows Vista`) includes, among others, the `Light` and `Semilight` subfamilies. But in `KFontView`, for both of them, the name of the subfamily is shown as 'Light'.

However, as is clear from the following screenshots, the two subfamilies are clearly not the same, despite the fact that `KFontView` calls them both 'Light':

[image]

[image]

On the other hand, `LibreOffice` `Writer` correctly labels these two subfamilies as `Light` and `Semilight`:

[image]

Here are the outputs of `otfinfo -i` for the two fonts:

```
otfinfo -i segoeuil.ttf
Family:              Segoe UI Light
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           Segoe UI Light
PostScript name:     SegoeUI-Light
Preferred family:    Segoe UI
Preferred subfamily: Light
Version:             Version 5.62
Unique ID:           Segoe UI Light
Manufacturer:        Microsoft Corporation
Vendor URL:          https://docs.microsoft.com/typography/about
Trademark:           Segoe is a trademark of the Microsoft group of companies.
Copyright:           © 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved. 


otfinfo -i segoeuisl.ttf
Family:              Segoe UI Semilight
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           Segoe UI Semilight
PostScript name:     SegoeUI-Semilight
Preferred family:    Segoe UI
Preferred subfamily: Semilight
Version:             Version 5.62
Unique ID:           Segoe UI Semilight
Manufacturer:        Microsoft Corporation
Vendor URL:          https://docs.microsoft.com/typography/about
Trademark:           Segoe is a trademark of the Microsoft group of companies.
Copyright:           © 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
```

In `FontForge`, segoeuil.ttf has Weight Class 300 (in Element -> Font Info… -> OS/2 -> Misc.), while segoeuisl.ttf has Weight Class 350.

Furthermore, if I open segoeuisl.ttf (that's the `Semilight` one) in `FontForge` and save it as an .sfd file, nowhere in that file can I see the word 'light' on its own, only 'semilight'. And yet, `KFontView` displays its subfamily name as 'Light', not 'Semilight'.

Finally, if I now reopen the .sfd file in `FontForge` and generate the font anew, `KFontView` still shows the subfamily as 'Light'.

Here are the details about my system:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-105-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

### Questions:

1. From where in a .ttf file does `KFontView` read the subfamily name (the name it displays after the comma in the name of the font)?
2. Using free tools such as FontForge, how could one modify a font so that `KFontView` displays the correct subfamily name?